# Como puedo quitarle el paginado a una tabla VDataTable en vuetify con vue

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, vue.js, vuetify, ts

Este es mi codigo en el cual intento quitar el paginado:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer usando la propiedad **hide-default-footer**

```
<v-data-table
:headers="headersListaPersonas"
:items="slotProps.item.listaPersona"
hide-default-footer
>
</v-data-table>
```